# htaccess syntax on CMS CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system

I am currently creating a CMS using CI. I have the following htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

this works fine for me but when I try to access mywebsite.com/admin/user/login the page is not found. What can I do about it?